# Run program on end user computer without Visual Studio

Tags: end-user

I wrote a program in VB.NET and created DLL files and used the COM objects in the registry. Now I want to run my program on another computer where I don't have Visual Studio. I am confused which files from my original project should I copy, where to copy and what to do afterwards? The question might seem too general but its the first time I have to run my program on other computers, so any help would be highly appricieated.